# Remote Debugging ASP.NET VSCode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I have an ASP.NET/IIS site setup using vagrant. Is there a way to remote debug from VSCode on my local machine? Having a difficult time find info on this
I see remote debugging but it sounds like it's only for visual studio
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2017

Comment: Nobody has tried this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_remote-debugging) remote debugging is not part of VS Code:

> VS Code does not support 'remote debugging' by itself. Remote debugging is a feature of the debug extension you are using and you should consult the extension's page in the Marketplace for support and details.